# Does RxJava Completable only triggers onComplete if the response is 2xx?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit with RxJava in Android and making a POST request that returns a Completable.

If it can reach the server and the POST is successful it returns 2xx and it triggers `onComplete`.

If for example i have no internet it triggers `onError`.

What happens if it reaches the server and the POST returns a non 2xx code? Does it trigger `onComplete` too or `onError`?

If it triggers `onComplete`, how can i check if it the POST was successful?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All non-2xx codes will trigger onError()